# WriteFile thread safety

Tags: file-io, thread-safety

Is WriteFile thread safe? I mean,can I write the same file from multiple threads simultaneously without synchronization? MSDN says nothing about thread safety of WriteFile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is thread safe by its own, i.e it prevents system from crashing, win API maintain internal locking when writing files and that lock is byte-range locks. You can read more here
[File locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking)